# How to pass selected value to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VisualForce page that should pass the selected value to the controller action based on the selection but I'm getting the null

`employee__c.dept_c` is a picklist datatype

Here is my following Visualforce page:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!employee__c.dept_c}">                    
  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!deptOnChange}" />                  
  <apex:param name="re" value="{!employee__c.dept_c}" assignTo="{!selectedDept}" />
</apex:inputField>
```

Controller:

```
public string selectedDept {get;set;}

public void deptOnChange()
{
   system.debug('deptOnChange: ' + selectedDept ); 
}
```

Comment: can you try adding a rerender for the action support. Not sure it fixes, but had similar issues earlier and fixed after adding rerender

Comment: i have added rerender to the action support still getting `null` in the system.debug

Comment: You may want to rename your method to `getselectedDept`. Remove the Apex properties from the variable name when you do.

Comment: still not getting the value i have done the following changes `    <apex:inputField value="{!employee__c.dept_c}">                    
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getselectedDept}" />                  
      <apex:param name="re" value="{!employee__c.dept_c}" assignTo="{!selectedDept}" />
    </apex:inputField>


    public void getselectedDept()
    {
       system.debug('deptOnChange: ' + selectedDept ); 
    }`

Comment: here's an example of the same problem + solution:http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/59920/apexparam-not-assigning-value-within-apexactionsupport-for-apexinputcheckbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I able to figured out, hope this will help others:

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="employeeCtrl">
 ......
 ......
<apex:inputField value="{!employee__c.dept_c}">                    
  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!deptOnChange}" />   
</apex:inputField> 
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
 Employee__c emp; 

 public employeeCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
 {        
     emp = (Employee__c)controller.getRecord(); 
 } 

 public void deptOnChange()
 {
   system.debug('deptOnChange: ' + emp.dept_c); 
 }
```