# apex:Param not working with CommandButton component

Tags: visualforce, dml, apex-param

I try to pass a parameter from Visualforce to the controller via `apex:param` and then upsert the object in the controller. However, the parameter I passed on, "`Field__c`" did not get written to the database. Here is my code:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}">
    <apex:param value="Saved" AssignTo="{!item.Field__c }" name="Saved"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

**Controller:**

```
public PageReference Save() {
    try {
        item.NumberContacts__c = itemOld.NoContacts__c;
        update item;
    }   
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Exception occurred '+String.valueOf(e));
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

After reloading, `item.Field__c` should get displayed on an output field on the Visualforce page, but after hitting the command button, it still displays the old value, not the value "**Saved**".
What do I miss here?

Comment: You'd have to query and rerender the updated information if you are not navigating to standard detail page.

Comment: Does your object `item` has the `Field__c` in its definition **inside the controller**? in other words, where is `Field__c` in the controller?

Comment: I retrieve the information for the object item via soql initially. Via apex:param the value for item.Field__c gets updated. I do not think I need to query again. 

The new value does not even get written into the database, so I do not think rerendering helps much as a first step.

Comment: Yes, Field__c gets queried for "item" in the getter method of the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a property in your controller, like

`public propField {get;set;}`

and assign it to the `item.field__c` like

`item.field__c = propField;`

Now, in your VF, set the property, like

`AssignTo="{! propField }"`

> **Explanation**

When your VF page loads, it will feed the property `propField` with the parameter. Once your object `item` is ready, you can then set its `Field__c` value with the property 'propField' inside the controller.

As you might have already guessed now, that using `item.Field__c` didn't do anything because your object might not had been ready when the VF page loaded.

> **Update**

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm), `apex:param` can only be a child of the following items:

- `<apex:actionFunction>`
- `<apex:actionSupport>`
- `<apex:commandLink>`
- `<apex:outputLink>`
- `<apex:outputText>`
- `<flow:interview>`

Try, changing your `commandButton` to `commandLink`.

> **What's wrong with CommandButton?**

Apparently, there seems to be bug with setting the property with this component if `apex:Param` is used. Thanks to [Jeff Douglas](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/), there is a workaround to use CommandButton and still be able to set the property value.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{! Save }" rerender="hiddenBlock">
    <apex:param name ="Saved"
                value="Saved"
                assignTo="{! propField }"/>
    </apex:commandButton>

<apex:pageBlock id="hiddenBlock" rendered="false"></apex:pageBlock>
```

All Hail, Jeff! for the CommandButton workaround.

Comment: Thank you, with propField the update functions well, just that the value "Saved" still does not get passed on and propField is null.

Comment: @user40501 CommandButton doesn't seem to be supported by the apex:param, try changing it to CommandLink.

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like the rerender might have been your issue. For anyone else running into similar issue.

Per, [apex:param not assigning value within apex:actionSupport for apex:inputCheckbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/59920/apexparam-not-assigning-value-within-apexactionsupport-for-apexinputcheckbox)